# In tkinter how do I get (don't really know how to describe sorry) hidden labels that only appear once a button has been clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

So for fun / practice I'm making a little program to help my friend choose what car to play in Rocket league, after each game he puts his stats into the program. So I have a lot of buttons (each button is labeld as a car), and once he presses the button I want several labels to appear at the bottom of the program with the stats for that car he has atm, and then I'll give him buttons next to the labels for him to change the stats.
A little bit of the example:

```
def octane_stats():
    """A button that produces the octane stats"""
    global s_s, ss_label, window
    octane_button = Button(window, text='Octane Stats')
    octane_button.grid(row=1, column=0)    

def main():
    """The main window that calls each cars buttons"""
    global s_s, ss_label, window
    window = Tk()
    s_s = "DON'T USE THE F***ING SCARAB!"     #s_s means scarab sucks
    ss_label = Label(window, text=s_s)        #ss being an even shorter s_s
    ss_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)
    octane_stats()
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

So that way when he presses the 'Octane Stats' button, I'll have 4 new labels + buttons appear in row 2, column(s) 0-8. But to have those hidden until he presses the button, obviously different stats will appear for the different buttons he presses, but I don't think I needed to include those buttons lol.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a frame for each car and put those labels and button in it. Create an empty frame before he presses (or choose a default car that shows up before he presses any button). Frames should have backgrounds so they could hide the frames underneath them.
Now whenever the button for that frame (car) is pressed use `that_frame.tkraise()` to put it on top of the others.
Before he presses if you don't want any stats to show up just raise the empty frame to cover up the others (or as I mentioned, raise the default frame if you want.)